# How to get Sorted column name and sort order in sort command of Telerik GridView

Tags: asp.net, .net, telerik, telerik-grid

I've straight forward question that how I can fetch the Name of `Sorted column` with the `sort order` in `sort command` of `Telerik Grid View`?

Looking forward for your replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it my self. I appreciate the answers i get on this question.
But it was quite easy to do as below:

`e.SortExpression` returns the name of sorted column

`e.NewSortOrder` returns the sorting order (asc or desc)

Answer (score 1):

you can get unique name like this:

```
protected void RadGrid1_SortCommand(object source, GridSortCommandEventArgs e) 
{ 
   foreach(GridColumn col in RadGrid1.MasterTableView.RenderColumns) 
    if (col is GridBoundColumn && (col as GridBoundColumn).DataField == e.SortExpression) 
        RadAjaxManager1.Alert(col.UniqueName); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean in a function on your controller. If 'ExampleFunction' is the one that is bound to your .Read() in your grid:

```
    public ActionResult ExampleFunction([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        SortDescriptor sortDescriptor = request.Sorts.FirstOrDefault();

        if(sortDescriptor != null)
        {
            if(sortDescriptor.SortDirection == ListSortDirection.Ascending)
            {
                switch(sortDescriptor.Member)
                {
                    case "Column1":
                        // Sort on Column1
                        break;
                    case "Column2":
                        // Sort on Column2
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                switch(sortDescriptor.Member)
                {
                    case "Column1":
                        // Sort on Column1 (descending)
                        break;
                    case "Column2":
                        // Sort on Column2 (descending)
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Set default sorting
        }

        // Do Other Stuff
    }
```